# Detect missing ID field using negetive look-ahead regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a file content as :-

```
$form->AddFields({
    id => 2048
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});

$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});

$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    id => 1024,
    value => 0,
});
$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'abc',
    value => 10,
});
```

Now, i need to find those AddFields function which do not have an ID field present in them (id=>).
I have done it using a awk command :-

```
awk '/form->AddFields/{ printf /id =>/? FS: $0 RS}' RS='});'
```

But i need to do the same using regular expression. I know we need to use negetive look-ahead feature. But i am not sure how to do it.

Expected Output :-

```
$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});
$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'abc',
    value => 10,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex can be little longer than awk

```
/\$form->AddFields\({(?![^}]+id =>)[^}]+}\);/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eF5pT9/1)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
\$form->AddFields([^)](?!\sid =>))+\);
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/HtavsP8BEf)